Как упаковать консольное node.js приложение вместе с библиотеками (модулями) в exe?
Есть файл index.js и папка с модулями. Как мне это упаковать в exe файл и возможно ли это вообще?

довольно много способов. можно самим nodejs https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html, можно взять electronjs, vercel/pkg + vercel/ncc, nw и ещё большое количество альтернатив
